# modified css for top bar in ubuntu linux

Tags: css, linux

I modified css file for top bar in linux. I colored text red in top bar.

Its working fine when some software lets say  browser opened but when I switched to desktop all css working  except color style.

```
#panel .panel-button{
       color: green;
}
```

screenshot when browser opened:

[image]

screenshot when switched to desktop:

[image]

and second issue is that nth-child not working .When I use

```
#panel .panel-button{
       color: green;
}

#panel .panel-button:nth-child(1){
       color: green;
}
```